# Древовидный вывод записей из базы данных

Tags: php, sql, kohana

Всем доброе время суток.
Работаю с kohana 3.3.2
Имеется таблица отделов, с полями "id", "name", "main_dep_id". Поле «main_dep_id» ссылается на поле «name» другого «id» этой же таблицы (т.е. отдел входит в дугой отдел и т.д.).
Для организации вывода данной таблицы в view, мне посоветовали:
- создать рекурсивный хелпер;
- передать в view не плоский массив, а дерево;
- скормить это хелперу.
Вопросы:
1. Я просмотрел в kohana все хелперы и так понял, нужно создавать свой хелпер?
2. Это получается в хелпере, создается готовый массив таблицы отделов?
3. Как рекурсивно обходить дерево департаментов и генерировать html, ведь html генерирует view, и рекурсию нужно писать в хелпере. 
**Не проще ли тогда написать своеобразный SQL-запрос, загнать его в переменную, ну и вывести ее в view? Или создать дополнительный массив ($departments1) отделов («id» c «name») и тогда в момент работы цикла (в view) формировать конечное view?**

Заранее **спасибо**.

Answer (score 2):

Приведу пример рекурсивного вывода дерева категорий:

Функция, строящая дерево, состоящее из вложенных массивов:

```
<?php 
class Helper_Util {   
    public static function build_tree( $ar, $pid = 0 ) {
        $op = array();
        foreach( $ar as $item ) {
            if( $item['parent'] == $pid ) {

                if ( !isset( $op[$item['id']])) {
                    $item['child'] = array();
                    $op[$item['id']] = $item;
                }
                // using recursion
                $children =  self::build_tree( $ar, $item['id'] );
                if( $children ) {
                    $op[$item['id']]['child'] = $children;
                }
            }
        }
        return $op;
    } 
}
```

Получаем записи из БД и строим дерево:
    // Вместо ORM удобнее будет использовать DB::select(...)
    $categories = ORM::factory('category')->order_by('parent')->order_by('index')->where('active','=','1')->find_all()->as_array();

```
$tree = array();
foreach ( $categories as $page) {
    $p = array(
        'id'     => $page->id,
        'name'   => $page->name,
        'parent' => $page->parent,
        'index'  => $page->index,
        'alias'  => $page->alias,
    );
    $tree[$page->id] = $p;
}

$result = Helper_Util::build_tree($tree);
```

Теперь нужно вывести полученное дерево во `view`. Если вы используете view написанные на языке php, вы можете создать рекурсивную функцию обхода дерева прямо внутри view.

Я использовал шаблонизатор smarty. В этом случае есть 2 варианта:

1. Генерировать HTML код с помощью рекурсии в функции-плагине smarty

```
function smarty_function_render_tree($params, &$smarty) {
...
}
```

2. С помощью рекурсивных include (плохой способ с точки зрения проивзодительности). Выдрано из рабочего проекта:

page.tpl:

```
{include file="tree.tpl" tree=$categories tree_level=0}
```

tree.tpl:

```
{foreach from=$tree key="id" item="subtree"}
<li data-id="{$subtree.id}" id="tree_item_{$subtree.id}" {if $tree_level>0 && !empty($subtree.child )}class="closed"{/if}><span style="vertical-align: top;float: left;{if $tree_level==0}font-weight: bold;{/if}">{$subtree.name}</span>
    <div class="b-admin-sizes" id="tree_item_sizes_{$subtree.id}">
    {if !empty($sizelists[$subtree.id])}
        {foreach $sizelists[$subtree.id] as $sizelist_item}
            <div class="b-admin-sizes-item" data-size-list-id="{$sizelist_item->id}" title="{$sizelist_item->lists}">{if !empty($sizelist_item->description)}{$sizelist_item->description}{else}{$sizelist_item->lists|truncate:20:"..."}{/if} <img src="/public/img/x.gif" class="icon icon-delete delete_sizelist" alt="Delete" title="Delete" ></div>
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
    </div>
    <img data-type="{$product_type}" src="/public/img/x.gif" class="icon icon-add add_size" alt="Add size" title="Add size" alt="Add size" style="margin-left: 5px">
        {if !empty($subtree.child )}<ul>
        {include file="tree.tpl" tree=$subtree.child tree_level=$tree_level+1}
        </ul>
        {/if}
</li>
{/foreach}
```